# How can I align a text that has a specific width at the center of a div?

Tags: html, css

This is the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92Uu7/)
I want to align group 2 to the center of the div so that the bottom border of the div be aligned to the middle of the text. However when I assign the text a width, it cannot be aligned to the center. If I remove the width, then the text takes up the whole line, so that the bottom border of the div cannot been seen. How shall I solve this problem?

HTML code:

```
<div class="group-name">
    <p>Group1</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.group-name{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
}
.group-name p{
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: -9px;
  width:100px;


  font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #16A085;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried `text-align:center`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your description, it looks like you are trying to put your text centered and in the middle of the border of the parent div:

```
.group-name{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
  width:100%;
  height: 10px;
}
.group-name p{
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto -7px ;
  background: #fff;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/92Uu7/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to give the .group-name p -> margin: 0 auto;

```
.group-name p{
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: -9px;
  width:100px;

  /* add this line */
  margin: 0 auto;

  font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #16A085;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in the center together with a width you can do.

```
group-name{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
}
.group-name p{
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: -11px;
  width: 60px;
  font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #16A085;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92Uu7/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `margin:auto` (or `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`) to align block level elements to the middle of the line if you are setting a width on them

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/92Uu7/6/)

Otherwise you could make the element an `inline-block` element and then give it a width:

[inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/92Uu7/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `text-align` property

```
text-align:center;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/92Uu7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

just add `text-align` to your css class like this :

```
  .group-name{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

[**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/92Uu7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/92Uu7/2/)

```
.group-name {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
}
.group-name p {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom: -9px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #16A085;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use text-align

```
text-align: center;
```

You talk about group 2 but it is nowhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `text-align` and `text-decoration` properties

```
.group-name p{
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: -9px;
  font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #16A085;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;

  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update following CSS -

```
.group-name{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use text-align property

```
.group-name{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
    text-align:center;
}
```